# How to default all routes to a specific folder in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have a folder called home that I'm using to organize my top level view files.  How do I set the route so that when they appear the url doesn't contain the /home/ section.

Example:  Currently the file about_us displays http://somesite.com/home/about_us where I want it to display http://somesite.com/about_us

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails 2.x way of doing this is

```
map.connect "/:action", :controller => "home"
```

this will map `somesite.com/somepage` to the `somepage` action on the `HomeController`

If you want to use a single action for everything, you may go for

```
map.connect "/:page", :controller => "home", :action => "page"
```

and then in your `HomeController`

```
class HomeController < ActionController::Base
  def page
    render params[:page]
  end
end
```

and of course, with this setup, you can name your views in `app/views/home` after the actual page names

Answer (score 3):

match is specific to rails 3. to handle this in rails 2.3.8 you want to do this:

```
map.about_us "/about", :controller => "home", :action => "about_us"
```

Answer (score 2):

One way would be to do this:

```
match 'about_us', :to => "home#about_us"
```

If you have multiple actions you want to perform in this way, use this:

```
match ':action', :controller => "home"
```

Comment: I'm using rails 2.3.8 and this is throwing an error for not knowing what match is